# Ratio test convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n\sqrt[n]{n}}
$$

I tried to show this converges by ratio test but got stuck at simplying the root, is that the right approach?

Comment: You could compare. Do you know what $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \root n \of n$ is?

Comment: okay 1 so i should sue comparison test?

Comment: You could. ${1\over n\root n\of n}\ge {1\over n\cdot 2}$, in fact.

Comment: But 1/2n diverges? So the above series actually diverges!

Answer (score 0):

Use *equivalents* :

$\sqrt[n]{n}\sim_\infty 1$, so $\;\dfrac1{n\sqrt[n]{n}}\sim_\infty\dfrac1n$, which diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The approach using the ratio test does not sound simple, however, since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/n}{1/(n\sqrt[n]{n})}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$$
, the convergence (divergence) of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n$$ implies the convergence (divergence) of the said series. (a.k.a. The limit comparison test)

Since the harmonic series diverges, your series also diverges.